# Set the if condition to true in PHPUnit test case

Tags: event-observer, magento2.3, phpunit

I have an if condition inside an observer as follows

```
public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        if ($observer->getData('status') == Status::REQUIRED) {
            //implementation 
        }
    }
```

Now I want to write a PHPUnit test for above.

How can I do so? basically, I want to know how can I bypass the if a condition or set it to true in my unit test.

**EDIT**

//implementation looks something like below

```
if ($observer->getData('var_first') == 'var_first_value') {
            $data = $observer->getData('var2')->getData();
            ........
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used following code to make the test work

```
    $this->observerMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Observer::class)
                ->setMethods(['getData'])
                ->disableOriginalConstructor()
                ->getMock();

   $this->observerMock->expects($this->atLeastOnce())
                ->method('getData')
                ->withAnyParameters();
```

Answer (score 2):

I think in you can mock your `Observer` class with `getData` method

i.e

```
$eventObserverMock = $this->getMockBuilder(Observer::class)
            ->setMethods(['getData'])
            ->disableOriginalConstructor()
            ->getMock();
```

Now `getData` method is mock so you can set the some value with return type which you want `true` or `false`

```
        $eventObserverMock
        ->expects($this->any())
        ->method("getData")
        ->with('status')
        ->willReturn('some value'); // here you can set your value which you want and use `$eventObserverMock` while calling your `execute` method
```

i.e

`$this->someclass->execute($eventObserverMock)`

**EDIT**

If you have multiple parameters then you can pass with comma separated like `->with($some,$demo`) and If you don't care about your parameter or you have lots of parameters then you can write like `->withAnyParameters()`

And for multiple calling, you can play it here `->expects($this->any())` with `$this->exactly(1)` here you need to replace 1 with your calling method count

Comment: What if there are multiple calling of getData() with different params?

Comment: Please see my edit.. @AnshuMishra

Comment: Then how will I manage the return value because based on the parameter return value is changing.

Comment: Means what will I put inside the ->willReturn()

Comment: you can put any value which you want like "test" or "demo" or anything @AnshuMishra

Comment: In this case, you need to create a different method for each return value. like `testSomeWithTrue` and `testSomeWithFalse` @AnshuMishra and in this different method you can play with your return value

Comment: I have updated the question, please take a look.